# How to get publish permissions properly in facebook api for android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app which logs into facebook using the facebook login button. After a user has successfully logged into facebook, I need to get publish permissions. How do I do this?

Information:
1. After a sucessful login, the app opens a new activity to publish stuff to facebook.
2. Every method I've tried either ends up getting the permission and then crashing the app or crashing the app altogether.

Any help would be highly appreciated as I'd tried all the tricks I could find but none of them seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the default facebook login button ?

Comment: Yes, as they've described in the Login tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way if you're using the default facebook login button :

```
authButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

If you already have a session open, without publish permissions :

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
if (!permissions.contains("publish_actions")) {
     Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"))
            .setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.FRIENDS);
     session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
}
```

You might also want to check handleAnnounce() method in the following link.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/Scrumptious/src/com/facebook/scrumptious/SelectionFragment.java#L268

Regarding the crash, please provide the crash log.